# Firestore: onSnapshot duplicates results

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I want to retrieves some data from Firestore using onSnapshot for real-time query. However i don't understand how and where use it, because when i try to put it inside my code, it duplicate all the results that i preaviously have.

I read in the documentations that i should use docChanges() or re-initialize the array as empty, but i think that something wrong in my code:

```
 const query = () => {
      setFavorites([]);
        const clientDoc = db.doc('Clients/' + id);
        return (
            clientDoc.get().then(client => {
                const favoritesRef = client.data().Favourites;
                favoritesRef.map(ref => {
                    db.doc(ref).onSnapshot(favorite => {
                        setFavourites([]);
                        const favoriteData = favorite.data(); // this is our favorite data
                        if (favoriteData) setFavorites(fts => [...fts, favoriteData]); // if favorite exits add to state
                    });
                });
            })
        )
    }
```

The structure of firestore is that: into the collection "Clients", i have a field called "Favourites" that is an array of strings. Those strings are something like: "/Restaurants/{idRest}". With this query i want to take those strings and retrieve the data of the collections represented by those strings.

I want to use the onSnapshot function because in another page i can add new favourites to the db, and i want that this page will update.

Comment: Im not sure how serFavorites is implemented but should it be something like this?

if (favoriteData) setFavorites([favoriteData]); // if favorite exits add to state

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

inside the arrow function of onSnapshot you're executing `setFavourites([])`, but the way react works it doesn't assure you to actually update the state before the next `setFavourites` you run.

I would update that part of your code to:

```
favoritesRef.map(ref => {
                    db.doc(ref).onSnapshot(favorite => {
                        const favoriteData = favorite.data(); // this is our favorite data
                        if (favoriteData) setFavorites( [favoriteData]); // if favorite exits add to state
                        else setFavorites([]);
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Doing like you said it doesn't show me all the list of favourites that already exists